# Apache 2.4 unixgroup authentication not working

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, unix

`Require unix-group` is not working for me when configuring the VirtualHost for my Apache server. Whenever I log in using pwauth, the server still authenticates users who are not members of the group that I specify. The attempted changes to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` can be shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ratman@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aperture-apache-server

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
    
    <Directory /var/www/aperture-apache-server/employees>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            IndexIgnore ..
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing
            DirectoryIndex index.html /employees/_h5ai/public/index.php
            
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Login"
            AuthBasicProvider external
            AuthExternal pwauth
            
            Require valid-user
            Require unix-group aperturestaff
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, I decided to switch away from `mod_authnz_unix_group` to a more primitive method: the `unixgroup` binary that you can install alongside `pwauth`. I ran `chmod u+s pwauth` on it and moved it to `/usr/sbin/`. My resultant configuration changes to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` are shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ratman@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aperture-apache-server

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
    AddExternalGroup unixgroup /usr/sbin/unixgroup
    SetExternalGroupMethod unixgroup environment
    
    <Directory /var/www/aperture-apache-server/employees>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            IndexIgnore ..
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing
            DirectoryIndex index.html /employees/_h5ai/public/index.php
            
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Login"
            AuthBasicProvider external
            AuthExternal pwauth
            GroupExternal unixgroup
            
            Require valid-user
            Require group aperturestaff
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But then, Apache fails to start, saying:

> Aug 22 17:43:39 aperture-mainframe systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
> Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
> Defined-By: systemd
> Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
> A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
> The job identifier is 2860 and the job result is failed.

Please help me configure group-based authentication on my Apache server (no, I do not want to use a .htpasswd file for protecting this directory, I want it done via VirtualHost)! I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Try `apachectl configtest` and `apachectl start`. Check the error_log if the reason is not explained on stderr.

Comment: The error given to me when I run a config test is
```AH00526: Syntax error on line 26 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Unknown Authz provider: group
```